# Json result Not Binding to aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, return-value

I have a service and it is returning json in the following format

```
Data {
    "TerminalID": 21,
    "TerminalName": "NewTested",
    "PortID": 27,
    "PortName": "Badu Island",
    "EffectiveStart": "2013-03-20T00:00:00",
    "EffectiveEnd": "2013-03-23T00:00:00",
    "ServiceID": 2
}
```

and in my aspx page my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divImageGo").click(function () {
            var valId = 2;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "VoyageOneService.svc/BindVoyageDetails" + valId,
                //data: '{"ServiceID":"2"}',
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {                                         
                    ServiceSucceeded(result);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    $("#errorDiv").text(msg);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

And success does the following:

```
function ServiceSucceeded(data) {
    alert("Success");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

        $("#dlistVoyageDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].TerminalName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].PortName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].EffectiveStart + "</td></tr>" + data.d[i].EffectiveEnd + "</td></tr>");
    }        
}

function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
    if (xhr.responseText) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        if (err)
            error(err);
        else
                error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
        }
        return;
    }
```

In this ..,

1. Iam getting My service called
2. Iam getting my Return value of json
3. Iam getting the Success fired with its alert msg

But I am unable to get the result. When I checked my alert with the result I am getting NULL

Comment: can you show service code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if condition and it will work.

As data.length is null hence you condition is not satisfied.

```
function ServiceSucceeded(data) {
    alert("Success");


        $("#dlistVoyageDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].TerminalName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].PortName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].EffectiveStart + "</td></tr>" + data.d[i].EffectiveEnd + "</td></tr>");

}
```

Comment: Data {
    "TerminalID": 21,
    "TerminalName": "NewTested",
    "PortID": 27,
    "PortName": "Badu Island",
    "EffectiveStart": "2013-03-20T00:00:00",
    "EffectiveEnd": "2013-03-23T00:00:00",
    "ServiceID": 2
}

Comment: This is the return value of json